# while the apk runs without problems on emulator when installed on Motorola milestone picture and icon doesn't shown as they were on emulator

Tags: android

my problem : the app I have uploaded into my cellular device is shown **without the pictures I have insert to it** .

---

steps I have done in order to install:

1. I have inserted the xxx.apk file into the device via usb
2. I downloaded an apps installer via the Market
3. I opened the app using the installer and instead of picture an white background appeared
4. when I opened the xxx.apk file using file system I found the pictures.

---

note: even an application icon weren't appearing.
Apparently the res libary having problem to be bined to application.

- I might ness to add something to my appliction manifest?
- I might need to change something on  my device ? (I already made a change and enabled user's not Market application  )
- I would be very grateful for some life saving answer I need to show my work in a few days in this is the first time i tested her on a real devise.

I also tried an example as shown in hello android book the same example worked perfectly on the emulator where on my android device (Motorola milestone ) the picture and icon weren't shown

Please tell me what I might be doing wrong guys I need to apply my project back at uni(I was the only one in uni who did it on android and in my country most of pep don't even know what android is so getting help outside of forum's like this is not an option  ) so please please help me .

Comment: How is the NDK related to your app?

Comment: Are you using multiple folder for different screen densities? 

How is your drawable folder called?

Comment: it's inside res and its called drawable the file name is icon.png

Comment: I even tried an already made application made by others which was published for hello android http://pragprog.com/titles/eband2/source_code
i trird the openGl code and it worked on emulator where on my devise it had the bug which explained above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what app installer you downloaded from the Market, but you shouldn't need it.  You should be installing the app to your phone using the same SDK tools you used to install it to the emulator.  Ie, using Eclipse or the commandline "adb install" commmand.

I'm assuming you used the SDK tools to install the app to the emulators?  In which case, start there.  Start with looking at what you're doing different between when you installed unsuccessfully to your phone and when you installed to successfully to the SDK.

In my experiences so far, there should be *very* few differences between working with the emulator and working with the phone.

Comment: thank you although the problem was something about the examples I downloaded when i for the first time used my app (with 10 pic and data base and lots of goodies) i dont know why but hello world examples doesnt work well on my droid

Answer (score 0):

Well, something is wrong, but what is hard to tell from your question. What pictures are you talking about? Your drawable resources? My guess would be that your application works in the emulator (you **have** tested it?), but that it doesn't on the phone you're testing with. Have you checked the logcat output?

If you're developing from Eclipse, why not try a debugging session using the phone rather than the emulator?

Comment: 1.under drawable 2.DOES WORKS ON EMULATOR 3.logcat ? its on the real device !!! on the emulator it works just fine 4.i didnt know i can debug on a real device.

Comment: can someone comment about what I should do in order to make it work ? apparently in the device the drawable resources exist but the application does'nt use them , can someone explain to me what's wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to narrow down without more details, but a few notes:

1. Pontus has a point - what's your logcat output? You can use logcat on a real device. Maybe not yours unless it's rooted, but with many phones you can.
2. Do you link the drawable to your app in the manifest file?
3. How do you test on emulator vs. device? Do you right-click the app and choose "Run As -> Android Application"? Do you do that for both emulator and device?
4. When you run on the device, do you first sign it? If so, can you verify the jar/apk and see the contents? Is the drawable under res/drawable?

Comment: 1. i dont use the log cat ' i  as explained above not debugging on device but using a device.
2.how should i bind the two ?
3.on the emualtor i do what you wrote and it works, on the device i do as you can see above
4.i am not signing but when i open through the device and in file system choose the Browse File i can see the pictures under res
 when choossing open app manager  and install the app the app run without the pictures

Comment: 1. logcat works at all times (if it's not locked on your device). IF it works, you'll see the output from ALL applications.

2. In your AndroidManifest.xml:    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

Comment: 3. Where do you get the apk from? Is it the one in the bin directory? Also, what apps installer do you use? Why don't you just do "adb install (apk name)"? That, or use a file browser (like OI File Manager) to point to the apk and open it. Or, again, don't open an emulator, connect your device via USB, and do "Run As -> Android Application". It should offer you to install it to the phone.

4. I meant within the jar. You can look at the contents with "jar tf apkfile".

Comment: 1. I'am not connected to the computer 2. Yes it does 3.the apk is the bin file from the \myapp\bin\myapp.apk "adb install (apk name)" ?? where on my device? there's no terminal, no command line and on my windows , and I didnt get what you were saying about the jar thing ?